# indexing names in json using elasticsearch in couchdb

Tags: json, elasticsearch, couchdb, elasticsearch-river

I am trying to implement full-text query for my json documents. I want to search by title.

My json is as follows:

```
{  
   "release":{  
      "genres":{  
         "genre":"Electronic"
      },
      "identifiers":{  
         "identifier":[  
            {  
               "description":"A-Side",
               "value":"MPO SK 032 A1 G PHRUPMASTERGENERAL T27 LONDON",
               "type":"Matrix / Runout"
            },
            {  
               "description":"B-Side",
               "value":"MPO SK 032 B1",
               "type":"Matrix / Runout"
            },
            {  
               "description":"C-Side",
               "value":"MPO SK 032 C1",
               "type":"Matrix / Runout"
            },
            {  
               "description":"D-Side",
               "value":"MPO SK 032 D1",
               "type":"Matrix / Runout"
            }
         ]
      },
      "status":"Accepted",
      "videos":{  
         "video":[  
            {  
               "title":"The Persuader (Jesper Dahlbäck) - Östermalm",
               "duration":290,
               "description":"The Persuader (Jesper Dahlbäck) - Östermalm",
               "src":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHuQWcylaU4",
               "embed":true
            },
            {  
               "title":"The Persuader - Vasastaden",
               "duration":380,
               "description":"The Persuader - Vasastaden",
               "src":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rA8CTKKEP4",
               "embed":true
            },
            {  
               "title":"The Persuader-Stockholm-Sodermalm",
               "duration":335,
               "description":"The Persuader-Stockholm-Sodermalm",
               "src":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVdDhOnoR8k",
               "embed":true
            },
            {  
               "title":"The Persuader - Norrmalm",
               "duration":289,
               "description":"The Persuader - Norrmalm",
               "src":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hy47qgyJeG0",
               "embed":true
            }
         ]
      },
      "labels":{  
         "label":{  
            "catno":"SK032",
            "name":"Svek"
         }
      },
      "companies":{  
         "company":[  
            {  
               "id":271046,
               "catno":"",
               "name":"The Globe Studios",
               "entity_type_name":"Recorded At",
               "resource_url":"http://api.discogs.com/labels/271046",
               "entity_type":23
            },
            {  
               "id":56025,
               "catno":"",
               "name":"MPO",
               "entity_type_name":"Pressed By",
               "resource_url":"http://api.discogs.com/labels/56025",
               "entity_type":17
            }
         ]
      },
      "styles":{  
         "style":"Deep House"
      },
      "formats":{  
         "format":{  
            "text":"",
            "name":"Vinyl",
            "qty":2,
            "descriptions":{  
               "description":[  
                  "12\"",
                  "33 ⅓ RPM"
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      "country":"Sweden",
      "id":1,
      "released":"1999-03-00",
      "artists":{  
         "artist":{  
            "id":1,
            "anv":"",
            "name":"Persuader, The",
            "role":"",
            "tracks":"",
            "join":""
         }
      },
      "title":"Stockholm",
      "master_id":5427,
      "tracklist":{  
         "track":[  
            {  
               "position":"A",
               "duration":"4:45",
               "title":"Östermalm"
            },
            {  
               "position":"B1",
               "duration":"6:11",
               "title":"Vasastaden"
            },
            {  
               "position":"B2",
               "duration":"2:49",
               "title":"Kungsholmen"
            },
            {  
               "position":"C1",
               "duration":"5:38",
               "title":"Södermalm"
            },
            {  
               "position":"C2",
               "duration":"4:52",
               "title":"Norrmalm"
            },
            {  
               "position":"D",
               "duration":"5:16",
               "title":"Gamla Stan"
            }
         ]
      },
      "data_quality":"Complete and Correct",
      "extraartists":{  
         "artist":{  
            "id":239,
            "anv":"",
            "name":"Jesper Dahlbäck",
            "role":"Music By [All Tracks By]",
            "tracks":"",
            "join":""
         }
      },
      "notes":"The song titles are the names of Stockholm's districts."
   }
}
```

I have indexed the above document in elasticsearch using the following command :

```
curl -X PUT "http://127.0.0.1:9200/_river/smalldiscogs/_meta" -d" 
{
    ""type"": ""couchdb"",
    ""couchdb"": {
        ""host"": ""localhost"",
        ""port"": 5984,
        ""db"": ""smalldiscogs"",
        ""filter"": null
    },
    ""index"": {
        ""index"": ""smalldiscogs"",
        ""type"": ""smalldiscogs"",
        ""bulk_size"": ""100"",
        ""bulk_timeout"": ""10000ms""
    }
}"
```

My question is how to index only the title field. Please help?

Comment: Do you refer to the top-level `title` field, the ones in `videos.video.title` or the ones in `tracklist.track.title`?

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. I was referring to release.title. In this case, it would be "Stockholm". Just below artists tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the [elasticsearch-river-couchdb](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-river-couchdb) plugin, you can configure the river with a groovy script that will remove all the fields but the ones you specify.

An example is given in the [official documentation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-river-couchdb#removing-fields-using-a-script) of the plugin and simply amounts to add the following the `script` to the `couchdb` object:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_river/smalldiscogs/_meta' -d ' 
{
    "type": "couchdb",
    "couchdb": {
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 5984,
        "db": "smalldiscogs",
        "filter": null,
        "script": "var title = ctx.doc.release.title; ctx.doc.remove("release"); ctx.doc.title = title;"
    },
    "index": {
        "index": "smalldiscogs",
        "type": "smalldiscogs",
        "bulk_size": "100",
        "bulk_timeout": "10000ms"
    }
}'
```

The script looks like this and will simply remove from the document all the fields exception the `title` one:

```
var title = ctx.doc.release.title;     <--- remember the title
ctx.doc.remove("release");             <--- remove all fields
ctx.doc.title = title;                 <--- re-add only the title field
```